# VC++ create XML file but can not find method "appendChild()"

Tags: xml, visual-c++, msxml

I'm using vs2015/vc++ to generate a XML document.I follow a example from Microsoft document. First of all, I add this:

```
import "msxml6.dll"
using namespace MSXML2;*
```

Then in the main loop I add such codes:

```
HRESULT hr = pXMLDom.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument60), NULL,     CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("Failed to instantiate an XML DOM.\n");
    return;
}

try
{
    pXMLDom->async = VARIANT_FALSE;
    pXMLDom->validateOnParse = VARIANT_FALSE;
    pXMLDom->resolveExternals = VARIANT_FALSE;
    pXMLDom->preserveWhiteSpace = VARIANT_TRUE;

    // Create a processing instruction targeted for xml.
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMProcessingInstructionPtr pi =       pXMLDom->createProcessingInstruction(L"xml", L"version='1.0'");    
    pXMLDom->appendChild(pi);

    // Create a comment for the document.
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMCommentPtr pc = pXMLDom->createComment(L"sample xml file created using XML DOM object.");
    pXMLDom->appendChild(pc);

...... }
```

But the VS2015 always told me that class "MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument" has no member "appendChild". Also I could not compile it. I google a lot but could not find the answer. Does anyone know the reason? Thank you.

Comment: You haven't included the definition of pXMLDom. Go to what it is (IXMLDOMDocument?), right click, go to definition and check for the appendChild method. It should be there so it could be a typo but this should give you a definitive answer.

Comment: MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr pXMLDom;

Comment: @Mike I checked the definition by using right button, I got two: IXMLDOMNodePtr appendChild (
        struct IXMLDOMNode * newChild ); virtual HRESULT __stdcall raw_appendChild (
        /*[in]*/ struct IXMLDOMNode * newChild,
        /*[out,retval]*/ struct IXMLDOMNode * * outNewChild ) = 0;

Comment: I also get this error, but I can compile it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
    static_cast<MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr>(pXMLDom)->appendChild(pi);
```

I had the same problem and worked for me